# Store object reference to grain instance in grain state

Tags: c#, serialization, orleans

I have a grain `IContainerGrain` containing a list of `Node` objects. Objects of type `Node` need to be able to communicate with each other through this grain:

```
class Node {

    public IContainerGrain Container { get; set; } // This is an object reference (!) to the container grain

    private void TriggerExecution() {
        var receiverId = 123;
        Container.GetNode(receiverId).SendSomeMessage(); // Communicate through container grain
    }
}
```

Now I want to persist state of `IContainerGrain` containing the List of Node. Serialization of the grain's state triggers serialization of all contained `Nodes` which then triggers serialization of `IContainerGrain`. This is not supported and I get an exception.

#### My approach

My non-working approach is to mark Node.Container as `NonSerializable` and implement the following in the Grain:

```
public override Task OnActivateAsync()
{
    if (State.ContainedNodes == null)
    {
        State.ContainedNodes = new List<INode>();
    }
    foreach (var n in State.ContainedNodes)
    {
        n.Container = this; // On activation initialize container
    }
    return base.OnActivateAsync();
}
```

However, this does not work always and I keep obtaining NullReferenceExceptions in `Node.TriggerExecution()`, since the Container property is null.

#### Questions

1. What's the best way to be able to store an object reference to a grain from an object within this grain? I could easily use a grain reference, but that would make the `Container.GetNode(...)` operation slow. I am aware this problem would not exist if I used a 1:1 mapping of grains to `Node`, however this has too much overhead for my application.
2. Is Orleans serialization storing references as such or is it performing deep copies always? It would be great to have references left intact after serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

1. Was able to work around the problem by creating another container object within the `IContainerGrain`.
   Figured out the serializer was invoked because `GetNode()` was called from another grain instance.
2. I think the answer is references are left intact, but I'd still be happy to get this confirmed :)

Comment: 2. References are left intact, and they can be stored and retrieved in State. But the serialization format changed recently with the 1.0 to 1.1 upgrade, I had to write a migration. I refactored my grains to keep only grainid's in State.

Answer (score 0):

What is a number of grains in container?
Who is executing TriggerExecution ? Why client cannot immidietly call node grain?

If client would call node grain then you would benefit from having multiple gateways for dispersing your requests.

Also creating grain reference is not expensive - from your example i would not worry about creating new node grain reference if reference does not exists in container.

Best